# Force a delay when logging in over ssh

Tags: ssh, acl, cifs

I want to achieve a delay with the login over ssh on a Linux Server.

I will describe the scenario and why I might need that:

- I have a CIFS mount on the server (Domain joined) over fstab with multiuser option
- The user has his home directory on this mount which is managed by ACLs and MS AD
- with cifscreds the user authenticates himself against the AD to access the specified folder
- the home folder location ist specified by the sssd config
- the cifscreds credentials is handed over by pam in the login process

Now to the Problem:
The user initially logs onto the server (Domain joined) with his AD credentials and successfully enters the server. But the process is to fast for cifscreds so I will get an error on the first login and land on root /. The user does not have the rights to be on the mounted "home folder" at this time. A second later he would be.
So he logs off and back in, keyring is read, permission granted and he is in his mounted home directory.

So I need a delay in the whole ssh login process, so he reaches his home directory after the credentials are stored in the keyring.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using PAM? pam_exec.so can execute a custom script when authenticating the user or opening a session. Be careful; a possible DoS attack vector could be created.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a messy situation, but `echo sleep 1 >~/.bash_profile` would cause a delay of 1 second each time a bash shell is invoked for the user.

Comment: user bash shell (and home dir)  is not available at login time.

Comment: The problem is, that there is no local home folder on the first hand. The user is stuck at root with no rights. So no ~/.bash_profile.

Comment: Ahh right.  Maybe introducing a pam_delay module would help then ?  Example here, where it delays on authentication failure, so would need tweaking to delay on success... https://github.com/linux-pam/linux-pam/blob/master/libpam/pam_delay.c   Or have a play with sshd_config's ForceCommand param ?

Comment: If this is the only user on the machine, or every user on the machine is mounted the same way, then maybe this can go in `/etc/bash.bashrc`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I played with the ForceCommand and build a script which cd's the User always in his home directory. There is still the error message on the first login thou.  My Problem is still, that I can't identify where I have to slow down the whole PAM Process. pam_delay could then be the solution. Any ideas? I can paste the pam.d/ssh config